# How to install pip packages in Anaconda?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install pip packages inside Anaconda without success.

This is what I have tried
1) installation of pip in Anaconda in the base environment
(base) root@eris:/# conda install pip
2) installation of a package, e.g. nano, using pip
(base) root@eris:/# pip install nano

Unfortunately, when I call nano an error message says that nano command was not found.

When I run "conda list", in one output line I get 
nano                      0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi

This is what I get when I run "which -a pip"
/root/anaconda3/bin/pip

and this is what I get when I run "which -a python"
/root/anaconda3/bin/python

Simon

Comment: Are you sure nano package contains an executable called nano? You can try `pip show -f nano`

Comment: Are you trying to install nano the text editor? It's not a python package, so you won't find it in pypi.

Answer (score 2):

`conda activate environt_name` followed by `pip install package_name` should work and install the package in that specific environment (but only do it for packages that are not in a conda repository and use `conda install` otherwise).

> Unfortunately, when I call nano an error message says that nano command was not found.

Beware that `pip install nano` will install the [nano library from Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/nano/). From the output of `conda list` it seems that the library was installed. I have never used this library, but from its description in Pypi it is related to django and it does not seem to come with an executable. Don't confuse it with the `nano` text editor that comes with most linux distributions (the nano text editor needs to be installed using your distro package manager).

---

Comment: The `nano` editor can also be installed with Conda: `conda install -c conda-forge nano`. I'd also emphasize [not to use `pip` in the **base** env](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment).